# Homomorphisms of a field into its valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring with quotient field $K$.  Let $k$ be a field contained in $R$.  What are the $k$-algebra homomorphisms $\operatorname{Hom}_k(K, R)$?  Are they all trivial?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. Can you share your thoughts on the problem and explain any ideas you have?

Comment: I think the key to providing a counterexample will be to exhibit a field extension $F/k$ such that $F\cong F((t))$ as $k$-algebras.  Then we can take $R=F[[t]]$ and $K=F((t))$.  Then the composition of the maps $K=F((t))\cong F\rightarrow F[[t]]=R$, gives a nontrivial $k$-algebra homomorphism.  To construct $F$ with the desired property, I would recommend letting $F_0=k$ and $F_{i+1}=F_i((t))$ for $i\geq 0$.  Then it seems intuitively plausible that $F=\varinjlim F_i$ would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to find a counterexample.

Find a field $k$ such that $k(y)$ embeds in $k$. Hint, try one that's algebraically closed. Then construct a DVR in between $k(y)$ and $k$, this is a fairly standard construction. My hint here would be to localize $k[y]$ in the correct manner.

Comment: Is there any way to determine when a DVR sits between a given extension?

Comment: @AlexYoucis You know, I really don't know.