# DVRs Sitting in an Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Prompted by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465515/homomorphisms-of-a-field-into-its-valuation-ring/465551?noredirect=1#comment1002388_465551) question, I was wondering if the following had any simple solution.

> > **Definition:** Let $L/K$ be any extension of fields. Define $D(L/K)$ to be the set of all DVRs $R$ such that $K\subseteq R\subseteq L$.

What can we say about $D(L/K)$? In particular, is it always non-empty? What are some non-trivial properties an extension $L/K$ might have such that $D(L/K)$ has a nice description? I would be particularly interested in the case where $L$ and $K$ are both local or global.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Claim:** $D(L/K)$ is empty iff $L/K$ is algebraic.

Assume that we have $R \in D(L/K)$, and let $\pi$ be a uniformizer. If $L/K$ is algebraic, then $K[\pi] = K(\pi) \subset R$, contradicting that $R$ is a DVR. Conversely, if $L/K$ is not algebraic, then $R = K[t]_{(t)} \in D(L/K)$ for any transcendental element $t \in L$.

It seems to me that to give $R \in D(L/K)$ is equivalent to giving a intermediate field extension $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$ and $t \in L$ such that $t$ is transcendental over $M$, resulting in $R = M[t]_{(t)}$. However, I have not thought this through entirely, so I make no claims as to its correctness.

Comment: I should have thought about this for longer than five minutes. That was extremely simple. Thanks!